# How to extract account number in cheque/check images

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am working on a task to extract the `account number` from `cheque images`. My current approach can be divided into 2 steps

1. Localize account number digits (Printed digits)
2. Perform OCR using OCR libraries like `Tesseract OCR`

The second step is straight forward assuming we have properly localized the account number digits

I tried to localize account number digits using `OpenCV` contours methods and using `MSER` (Maximally stable extremal regions) but didn’t get useful results. It’s difficult to generalize pattern because

- Different bank cheques have variations in template
- Account number position is not fixed

How can we approach this problem. Do I have to look for some `deep learning` based approaches.

**Sample Images**
[image]

Comment: The account number is at the very bottom, right? Usually, the cheque I see does not have an explicit Ac No field as above

Comment: @cuongptnk no that is the bank routing number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone for the suggestions, I ended up training deep learning object detection method to localize Account number and it gave very good results as compared to OpenCV based methods

Comment: Hi @arush , can u tell me how to get the account number . Basically I want to extract the data from the aadhar card .I have used the template to make a boundary box  (labelImg).Any apply the input images but I could the good result can u tell me how to apply the deep learning model to detect the text and extract the text ?

Comment: Hi @Saini aadhar card template is less complicated as compared to cheque image template and I think it only contains printed characters, so OpenCV should be enough to detect text (for recognition part you can use tesseract ocr). I believe deep learning method will be overkill for your task

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the account number has the unique purple text color, we can use color thresholding. The idea is to convert the image to HSV color space then define a lower/upper color range and perform color thresholding using `cv2.inRange()`. From here we filter by contour area to remove small noise. Finally we invert the image since we want the text in black with the background in white. One last step is to Gaussian blur the image before throwing it into Pytesseract. Here's the result:

[image]

Result from Pytesseract

```
30002010108841
```

Code

```
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import cv2

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([103,79,60])
upper = np.array([129,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 10:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

mask = 255 - mask
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (3,3), 0)

data = pytesseract.image_to_string(mask, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I like your solution. However, not sure if the purple assumption will hold. Need the OP to provide more details, I think.

Comment: Maybe just extract all sequences of numbers. Then apply some constraints for account number: min length, need to start with digits in a range, etc... I think that would be more reliable?

Comment: @nathancy Unfortunately account number does not have a fixed purple color and it should be inside the box

Comment: @cuongptnk Different banks have different patterns (i.e. number of digits) for account number, hence it would be difficult I believe

Comment: @arush1836 I think you need to come up with a list of knowledge that we can rely on: for example, "it should be inside a box" is a very good point to have since the first step is to locate the "candidate" box. The more information we have, the better we can come up the solution.

Comment: I think the bank name is always at the top left, right? If so, we can extract and identify the bank first. Then if else each case, with each bank, we have a unique pattern to extract the account number.

Comment: @arush1836 yes you would need a solid defining factor as to what you could describe an account number as. Using this defining feature we can extract the account number. Without this knowledge to isolate the box its difficult to determine what text to extract

Comment: @nathancy I have successfully localized box with OpenCV in which Account Number is written, then I tried [EAST text detector](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/) in the box to detect all the text but it’s not working, I might have to tune some parameters of EAST text detector. I plan to detect all text in the box then I will do some filtration to find account number.